# How to issue 0x2D interrupt in C code on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: c, windows, x86, x86-64, interrupt

I'm looking for a way to issue interrupt 0x2D from C code just like you can issue int 3 using `__debugbreak()`

On x86 I can use inline assembly

```
__asm
{
    int 2dh
}
```

but I need a solution that will work for:

- x64 and be Visual Studio specific (minimum requirement)
- x86 and x64, compiler independent (best solution)

Comment: I meant the interrupt 0x2D

Comment: User "too honest for this site" has a bad habit of pretending not to know what people meant in order to poke fun at them.  I regret that you had to experience this.

Comment: add separate asm file to project and compile it with `ml64 /c /Cp /Zi $(InputFileName) -> $(InputName).obj` for example. also you can call [`DbgPrompt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-dbgprompt)  which internal call int 2d with eax==2

Answer (score 3):

Since x64 Visual Studio doesn't support inline assembly at all (last I heard, anyway), your best compiler-independent solution is to write an `.asm` file that defines a function, let's call it `int_2d`, that just issues this interrupt and then returns.  You compile the `.asm` file to an object file, link that object file with the rest of your application, and you can then write `extern void int_2d(void);` in a header file and call it normally from C when you need to issue the interrupt.

For [the assembler that ships with x64 Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx), the `.asm` file should look something like this:

```
_TEXT segment 'CODE'

int_2d proc 
    xor eax,eax 
    int 2dh 
    nop
    ret 
int_2d endp 

_TEXT ENDS 
END
```

The `nop` after the `int 2dh` is necessary because, depending on the opcode used and whether or not the process has a debugger attached, the INT 2D handler may or may not cause one *byte* of code (not one instruction) immediately after the `int` instruction to be skipped.  So you need to put a one-byte NOP there.

INT 2D also expects an opcode in the A register; [known values of this opcode](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d1/dee/ndk_2kdtypes_8h_source.html#l00050) range from 0 to 5, and I'm not having any luck finding documentation on what they actually do.  The example code arbitrarily chooses to set A to 0.  (You don't need to save and restore it, because A is call-clobbered in all of the Windows calling conventions.)  If you want to pass the opcode as an argument, you can do that like this:

```
_TEXT segment 'CODE'

int_2d proc 
    mov eax, ecx
    int 2dh 
    nop
    ret 
int_2d endp 

_TEXT ENDS 
END
```

but you must then declare the function on the C side as `__fastcall void int_2d(uint32_t op);`  (The `__fastcall` is unnecessary, but harmless, when compiling in 64-bit mode, I think.)

Unfortunately I do not know how to write the "boilerplate" (all of the stuff other than the actual assembly instructions) for an `.asm` file that needs to work with as many different Windows toolchains as possible.  The above probably *won't* be acceptable to NASM, for instance.

Comment: the "boilerplate" for ml[64] will be `_TEXT segment 'CODE'

somefunc proc
    mov eax,*
    int 2dh
    int 3
    ret
somefunc endp

_TEXT ENDS
END`

Comment: @RbMm Would you please make that an edit? I don't know where to put the line breaks.

Comment: @RbMm What is the purpose of the `mov eax,1` and the `int 3`?  I didn't see anything calling for those in OP's question.

Comment: the `eax` must be initialized before call `int 2dh` - the windows handle `int 2dh` differently, based on `eax` value. now [known](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d1/dee/ndk_2kdtypes_8h_source.html#l00050) 5 values - say in case `BREAKPOINT_PROMPT` (2) windows generate exception breakpoint, when with 1,3,4 - auto handle it (in `KdpStub` if no kernel debugger attached). so set some correct value of `eax` is mandatory. after `int 2dh` windows synthetic increment `rip` (`eip`) by 1. as result we return (say after `BREAKPOINT_PRINT` (1)) exactly to `ret` - `int 3` (1 byte) will be skipped.

Comment: always need single byte instruction after `int 2dh` - say `nop` or `int 3`. this single byte (how minimum without debugger) always will be skipped and never executed. if we not insert this additional byte, but another instructions - we jump to the middle of next instruction (if it > 1 byte len) or skip `ret`.

Comment: more exactly if `rax`, when `int 2dh` called, in { 1,3,4,5 } set - no exception raised to application or user mode debugger (handled by `KdpStub` in kernel) .otherwise will be `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` generated with single parameter (value of `RAX` ). after `int 2dh` if it handled - we return to +1 byte forward (exactly to `ret` in my example)

Comment: @RbMm Thanks, I've done my best to summarize all of that in the text of the answer.

Comment: also exist interesting points how user mode debugger and application view exception (if *rax* not in `{1,3,4,5}`) - degugger (on first chance) view `rip` in context and exception address (from exception record) at the +1 from address after `int 2dh` (so at `ret` in my example), when user mode app view different exception address (+1) and context `rip` (+0 - so point to `int 3` in my code). this is points for some ati debug

Comment: for compile we can use `ml64 /c /Cp /Zi $(InputFileName)` -> `$(InputName).obj`

Comment: *EAX should be set* - exactly `RAX` for x64 must be - if say `RAX==0x8000000000000001` - will be exception, despite `EAX` is `1` here

Comment: @zwol: if you want the caller to supply the EAX value (i.e. `void int2d(uint32_t code)`, use `mov eax, ecx` (for the Windows x64 calling convention, or 32-bit `__fastcall`).  This will zero-extend into RAX..

Comment: The Windows x64 calling convention is also called `__fastcall`, so that's why it's harmless.  The difference from x64 `__vectorcall` is only in how `__m128` / `__m256` args are passed by value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. I will get my head around it and probably mark this as an answer soon. @RbMm do you know any article where the eax with int 2d byte skipping is fully described? I played with it recently and noticed it but I just can't seem to figure out the details when exactly its skipped and when it is not and how it helps to detect user-mode debuggers

Comment: @MarcinK. - look for [trap.asm](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ke/amd64/trap.asm). the `int 3` entry point is `KiBreakpointTrap` and `int 2d` entry is `KiDebugServiceTrap`. special look for line 1346 - `inc     qword ptr MfRip[rsp]` this is where return address is synthetic incremented by +1. look also to  line 340 - where in case `int 3` exception address is decremented by -1 (to point exactly to `int 3`). and study how [`KiDispatchException`](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Ke/amd64/exceptn.c#L430) worked. how Rip manipulated (line 497, etc)